# TP-link TL-WR841N OpenWRT cannot connect to internet

Tags: openwrt

I have TP-link TL-WR841N v11.1 router.
I made a flash to install openwrt-15.05.1-ar71xx-generic-tl-wr841n-v10-squashfs-factory firmware.
Unfortunately this installation does not provide GUI interface so I have to install it manually.
However in order to install Luci interface I have to first establish internet WAN connection to the router.
My ISP provides just Ethernet connector from the wall. I'm able to establish internet connection through Windows 10 on my laptop. When executed ipconfig there, the connection parameters are:

```
Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : chromservis.local
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Qualcomm Atheros AR8162/8166/8168 PCI-E Fast Ethernet Controller (NDIS 6.30)
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : B8-88-E3-8E-2B-6D
DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::a1fc:dd5c:1c69:d6d%14(Preferred)
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.140(Preferred)
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : neděle 25. září 2016 9:41:32
Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : neděle 2. října 2016 10:10:43
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.10
DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 246974691
DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1E-EC-44-D4-B8-88-E3-8E-2B-6D
DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.10
                                       8.8.8.8
NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

When I plug the Ethernet cable to WAN router port, the WAN control light on the router is blinking.
However I cannot establish internet connection through the router. My default  Openwrt WAN configuration is:

```
config interface 'wan'
option ifname 'wan'
option proto 'dhcp'
```

plus I tried to add:

```
option peerdns 0
option dns '192.168.0.10'
```

with no success.

When trying to ping IP adresses:

```
ping 8.8.8.8
ping 192.168.0.10
```

it says "Network unreachable".

I'm afraid I did not properly configured DNS.
Can somebody help me how to connect the router to internet?

Comment: Is your connection perhaps locked to your PC's MAC address?

Comment: I removed WAN configurations and edited LAN config as you mentioned and plug Ethernet cable into LAN1. Still no connection in web browser. After rebooting the router I cannot no longer access the router via 192.168.1.1 SSH Putty console :/ (Network error: No route to host), neither via any other IP address. How can I restore the configuration if I cannot reach the Putty console?